# Rubymotion Dispatch exiting early

Tags: rubymotion

I'm executing a fairly vanilla dispatch queue in Rubymotion, however it is apparently exiting early. It never gets past the initWithContentsOfURL call. However, removing the Dispatch::Queue wrapper and putting the calls in the main thread works.

The application in the simulator exits with no stack trace or indication of what went wrong. Am I mis-using the dispatch queue?

```
def foo
  Dispatch::Queue.concurrent.async do
    error_ptr = Pointer.new(:object)
    data = NSData.alloc.initWithContentsOfURL(
      NSURL.URLWithString(url), options:NSDataReadingUncached, error:error_ptr)
    unless data
      p error_ptr[0]
      return
    end
    json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:0, error:error_ptr)
    unless json
      presentError error_ptr[0]
      return
    end
    Dispatch::Queue.main.sync { print_results(json) }
  end
end

def print_results(json)
  p "#{json}"
end
```

Comment: Your code shows the `print_results` method being inline with your `Dispatch` call -- is it really set up that way, or is the `Dispatch` call contained within a different method?

Comment: It's not inlined. It's a separate call. The Dispatch should be enclosed in a method.

Comment: Well then your code works perfectly for me on RubyMotion 1.8; maybe it's an issue with the specific URL you're trying to load?

Comment: Thanks Dylan. You put me on the right track. If I set something like `url = "http://www.google.com"` that will fail. But if I put the string directly in the call to URLWithString, it works.

Comment: Weird. Where were you setting `url`? In the `foo` method, or somewhere else in your code?

Comment: After the `def foo` but before the `Dispatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I tracked down the issue. It was because I was declaring url in the method

```
def foo
url = "www.google.com"
  Dispatch
    take action on url
  end
end
```

By moving the url declaration in to the Dispatch thread, it works. I think it was a matter of a method local variable going out of scope before the task had time to execute.

```
def foo
  Dispatch
    url = "www.google.com"
    take action on url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now it seems that RubyMotion does not properly retain the local variables outside the dispatch block, so is probably getting an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS and crashing.  The following fails:

```
foo = "some value"
Dispatch::Queue.concurrent.async do
    puts foo
end
```

However the following two *will* work:

```
@foo = "some value"
Dispatch::Queue.concurrent.async do
    puts @foo
end
```

and also:

```
foo = "some value"
foo.retain
Dispatch::Queue.concurrent.async do
    puts foo
    foo.release
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, declaring url in method was fine in RubyMotion 2.5, but my app was crashing with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and sometimes with other error messages because of unicode characters in the app name and all over my code. Fixing encoding header and changing the app name solved my problem. Surprisingly, the app was working fine and crashed only when I called `initWithContentsOfURL`.